# Issue with searching for text within a returned string

Tags: string, search, beautifulsoup, html

I have wrote code that gets this returned:

```
<div id="IncidentDetailContainer"><p>The Fire Service received a call reporting a car on fire at    the above location. One fire appliance from Ashburton attended.</p><p>Fire crews confirmed one car   well alight and severley damaged by fire. The vehicle was extinguished by fire crews using two   breathing apparatus wearers and one hose reel jet. The cause of the fire is still under investigation   by the Fire Service and Police.</p><p> </p><p> </p></div>
```

I want to search through it and find the "Ashburton" part, but so far no matter what I use I get none returned or [].

My question is this: is this a normal string that can be searched (and I'm doing something wrong) or is it because I have got it from a webpage source code that I can't search through it the normal way?

It should be simple, I know, but still I get none!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import request
import sys, traceback

webpage = request.urlopen("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/IncidentsPast7days.cfm?siteCategoryId=3&T1ID=26&T2ID=35")
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
incidents = soup.find(id="CollapsiblePanel1")
Links = []
for line in incidents.find_all('a'):
    Links.append("http://www.dsfire.gov.uk/News/Newsdesk/"+line.get('href'))
n = 0
e = len(Links)
if e == n:
   print("No Incidents Found Please Try Later")
   sys.exit(0)
while n < e:
    webpage = request.urlopen(Links[n])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)
    station =  soup.find(id="IncidentDetailContainer")
    #search string
    print(soup.body.findAll(text='Ashburton'))
    n=n+1
```

Just FYI, if the webpage doesn't have any incidents today it wont search for anything (obviously) that's why I included the returned string, so if you run it and get nothing, that's why.

Comment: you want to find find the text that contains 'Ashburton' or the tag?

Comment: I got the  tag with the name in it but i want to search within the tag as the name will change and i want to search for different names eventually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide a pattern in the `text=`. From the `html` you have provided, If you want to find the `tag` that has "Ashburton" in it, you can use something like this,

```
soup.find_all('p', text=re.compile(r'Ashburton'))
```

You can get only the text by this,

```
soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r'Ashburton'))
```

Comment: Thanks so much that works even better! I'm eventually going to replace the name with a name selected from a list so instead of "Ashburton" it would be something like lstName.selected so if the user wants to search gor a different station they can! Thanks so much this this is the best part of my project done!  i will check it when  get home!

Comment: Just checked and sure enough it does work!! thank you so very much!! just one quick question, is it possible to substitute the 'Ashburton' for a variable that contains Ashburton? i.e. Station = "Ashburton"  soup.find_all(text=re.compile(rStation)) will mark question as answered. @salmanwahed

Comment: yes, You can do like this:
`soup.find_all('p', text=re.compile(r'{}'.format(Station)))`